# Random screen captures in Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a recent issue with my Galaxy Tab 10.1 where the screen capture function randomly activates, and it is driving me crazy. I did a factory reset and the problem persists.

It is more than accidental touching of the new quick reference key. It is completely random, most noticeable while whatching a movie etc.

Other than the factory reset, is there anything else I can do? In communication with Samsung, their only suggestion is to conduct the reset.

Answer (score 1):

What have you done after the factory reset -- installing *everything* you've had installed before? Best way to figure out where the problem is located is:

1. Backup as much as you can
2. factory-reset the device
3. do **not yet** install/restore anything!
4. check for a reasonable time whether the problem re-appears

   - if it does right after the factory-reset, your device needs go to support (or they need to send a firmware update/fix)
   - if it not re-appears, continue with 5.
   - if it does re-appear, you've found the app causing the issue. Break here, see below.
5. re-install/recover **ONE** app. Repeat from 4.

If above steps resulted in an app being the cause, you've got multiple choices:

- re-configure the app and see if you can make the error go away
- uninstall the app and see if the problem goes away
- if none of the two works, start with step 2. above and *skip* the bad app.